# Script to handle audio devices

Tags: windows, audio, script, automation

Would there be any way to use a script (any language) to enable one audio device (using id?), and disable two others. After that, then disable one input device.

Then a separate script, that would revert the changes done by the first script, which would disable one audio device, and enable two others. After that, then enable one input device.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a script is possible, and below is one utility that can disable and
enable devices that you may use in it. Writing the script itself
should be up to you.

You may use the Microsoft utility of
[Windows Device Console (Devcon.exe)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon),
downloaded from github
[DevCon-Installer](https://github.com/Drawbackz/DevCon-Installer)
(click "releases"),
to enable and disable drivers.

To see an example of using Devcon, see the post in
[ss64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/devcon.html).

The commands to disable and enable a device are:

```
devcon.exe disable "name of device"
devcon.exe enable "name of device"
```

The name of the device can be found in Device Management.